# :target to point to a .class and not to #id

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

is it a way to make the `:target` to point to a `.class` instead of a an `#id` so it can point for more than one element
a use case:

```
<style>
section:target{height: 60px}
section p:target{color:red}
</style>

    <div class="menu">
    <nav><a href="#foo">Collapse me</a></nav>
    <nav><a href="#bar" >Change my color</a></nav>
        <section id="foo">
            <p id="bar">hop</p>
        </section>
</div>

<div class="menu">
    <nav><a href="#baz">Collapse me</a></nav>
    <nav><a href="#boo">Change my color</a></nav>
        <section id="baz">
        <p id="boo">la</p>
        </section>
    </div>
```

imagine that it will work, then you can make the famous "*i'm here*" in the menu, **collapsing the page** and **showing where the user is** at **the same time**, so imagine, you make a picture for example, then you put `opacity:0` then when using target you let the value be `opacity:1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, plus it's not how the `:target` pseudo-class is meant to be used.

Anchor fragments in URLs can only ever point to one identifier at a time, so even if `:target` did look at classes, you wouldn't be able to apply styles to more than one element of a given class at a time. This is why anchor fragments are made to correspond to IDs, not classes.

If you need to target more than one element you should be using other CSS selectors or even JavaScript.

Comment: true.

try to use javascript with hash links or html5 history api

Comment: but html5 is still in draft, hope they'll add another :target designed to multiple selections.
NB: how to do this? jQuery?

Comment: can you please provide me a sample code? i've used learned html5 as my first thing to avoid javascrit, but here i'm struggling with scripted-solution-problems :(

Comment: javascript and html5 are not mutually exclusive ;)

Comment: @peat-ar yes but with HTML5 you can do a lot of things that was done in 4.1 using javascript (form controls, accordion effect)